observer seems not work well in my custom react bullet
I am using TypeScript in a React environment to implement a video bullet screen system. My idea is to use the sendBullet function to send bullets. The function will create a span element (bullet), add it to the bullets array, append it to the bullet container, and play an animation. At the same time, it will disable the track where the current bullet is located. I also start an observer, and when the element fully enters the bullet container, the track is enabled. I wrote some code based on this idea, but in the end, I couldn't achieve the effect. The code in the observer to enable the track seems to not execute, which confuses me a lot.
import { RefObject } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

class BulletBox {
    containerEl: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
    bullets: { el: HTMLSpanElement; track: number }[];
    tracksAvailable: boolean[];
    trackNum: number;
    bulletMax: number;
    bulletPool: HTMLSpanElement[] = [];
    observer: IntersectionObserver | null = null;

    constructor(
        bulletContainer: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
        trackNum: number,
        bulletMax: number
    ) {
        this.containerEl = bulletContainer;
        this.bullets = [];
        this.trackNum = trackNum;
        this.bulletMax = bulletMax;
        this.tracksAvailable = Array.from({ length: 6 }, () => true);

        this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            this.observerHandler.bind(this),
            {
                root: this.containerEl.current,
                threshold: 1,
            }
        );
    }

    getContainerW() {
        return this.containerEl.current?.clientWidth || 0;
    }
    getContainerH() {
        return this.containerEl.current?.clientHeight || 0;
    }
    getTrackHeight() {
        return this.getContainerH() / this.trackNum;
    }
    isBulletOverMax() {
        if (this.bullets.length > this.bulletMax) {
            // console.warn(`checkBulletNum: rech max`);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    observerHandler(entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
            const colorMap = {
                0: "red",
                1: "green",
                2: "blue",
                3: "yellow",
                4: "purple",
                5: "orange",
            };
            const track = (entry.target as HTMLSpanElement).dataset.track;
            if (entry.intersectionRatio === 1) {
                if (track === undefined) {
                    console.error(
                        "track not exist:",
                        (entry.target as HTMLSpanElement).dataset.id
                    );
                    console.error("Current bullets:", this.bullets);
                    //alert("Could not find bullet for target");
                    return;
                }

                (entry.target as HTMLSpanElement).style.color = colorMap[track];

                this.tracksAvailable[Number(track)] = true; //释放轨道
                console.error(
                    "bullet track release",
                    track,
                    this.tracksAvailable
                );
            }

            console.log(
                "bullet enter observerHandler",
                entry.intersectionRatio,
                (entry.target as HTMLSpanElement).dataset.track
            );
        });
    }
    toggleAnimation(status: boolean) {
        this.bullets.forEach((bullet) => {
            bullet.el.getAnimations().forEach((animation) => {
                if (status) {
                    animation.play();
                } else {
                    animation.pause();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    findFreeTrack() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.tracksAvailable.length; i++) {
            if (this.tracksAvailable[i]) {
                // console.error(this.tracksAvalible);
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    createBullet() {
        const bullet = document.createElement("span");
        bullet.style.position = "absolute";
        bullet.style.left = "0";
        bullet.style.cursor = "pointer";
        bullet.style.textShadow =
            "rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px 0px 1px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 1px 1px, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px -1px 1px, rgb(0, 0, 0) -1px 0px 1px";
        return bullet;
    }

    placeBulletOnTrack(bullet: HTMLSpanElement, trackIdx: number) {
        bullet.style.top = `${trackIdx * this.getTrackHeight()}px`;
        this.containerEl.current?.appendChild(bullet);
        const animation = bullet.animate(
            [
                {
                    transform: `translateX(${this.getContainerW()}px)`,
                },
                {
                    transform: `translateX(-100%)`,
                },
            ],
            {
                duration: 10000,
                easing: "linear",
                iterations: 1,
                fill: "forwards",
            }
        );

        animation.onfinish = () => {
            console.error(
                "bullet remove",
                bullet.dataset.track,
                this.tracksAvailable
            );
            this.bullets = this.bullets.filter((b) => b.el !== bullet);
            this.bulletPool.push(bullet);
            this.observer!.unobserve(bullet);
        };

        animation.play();
    }

    sendBullet(content: string) {
        const trackIdx = this.findFreeTrack();
        if (trackIdx === -1) {
            console.warn("no free track", content);
            return;
        }
        this.tracksAvailable[trackIdx] = false;

        let bullet = this.bulletPool.pop();
        if (bullet === undefined && this.isBulletOverMax()) {
            // console.warn("sendBullet: bullet over max");
            this.tracksAvailable[trackIdx] = true;

            return;
        }
        bullet = bullet || this.createBullet();

        bullet.innerHTML = content;
        bullet.style.color = "white";
        bullet.dataset.track = trackIdx.toString();
        bullet.style.backgroundColor = "none";

        console.log(
            "sendBullet",
            trackIdx,
            "lockTrack",
            trackIdx,
            this.tracksAvailable
        );

        //调好弹幕了

        this.bullets.push({ el: bullet, track: trackIdx });

        this.observer!.observe(bullet);
        this.placeBulletOnTrack(bullet, trackIdx);

        // console.warn("sendFinish");
    }

    render(bullet: HTMLSpanElement) {
        createRoot(this.containerEl.current!).render(<div>{bullet}</div>);
    }
}

export default BulletBox;



I tried to modify entry.intersectionRatio === 1 in the observerHandler function to entry.intersectionRatio > 0.9, but this caused the bullets to overlap. The purpose of disabling the track in my idea is to prevent many bullets from overlapping in the track. This doesn't seem to solve my problem.
